# Usando campo de busca e pagination com Function Based View no Django

Tags: django, funções, django-queryset, django-filter

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
#decorators.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def superuser_required(func):
    return user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated() and u.is_superuser)(func)


# views.py
@superuser_required
def dashboard_persons(request):
    persons = PersonProfile.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(persons, ENTRIES_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    persons = paginator.page(page)

    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_persons.html', {'persons': persons })

# dashboard_persons.html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Localizar..." name="search_box">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Dai eu queria criar um *campo de busca*.

Eu tentei:

```
# views.py
@superuser_required
def dashboard_persons(request):
    persons = PersonProfile.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(persons, ENTRIES_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    persons = paginator.page(page)

    q = request.GET.get('search_box')
    if q:
        persons = persons.filter(full_name__icontains=q)

    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_persons.html', {'persons': persons })
```

Mas eu perdi o raciocínio, porque reparem que eu tenho dois `request.GET.get.` E o `filter` seria feito depois, em `persons = PersonProfile.objects.all().filter(...)`

Alguém pode me ajudar a como resolver isso?

*2ª opção:* usar CBV. Eu saberia fazer, mas dai não sei fazer a autenticação usando o `LoginRequiredMixin` adaptado a `superuser_required`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Regis

acredito que o filtro tem prioridade sobre a paginação, pois primeiro você deve saber qual é o resultado do seu filtro e depois paginar os resultados retornados por ele.

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
@superuser_required
def dashboard_persons(request):
    persons = PersonProfile.objects.all()

    filter = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
    if filter:
        persons = persons.filter(full_name__icontains=filter)

    paginator = Paginator(persons, ENTRIES_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    persons = paginator.page(page)

    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard_persons.html', {'persons': persons, 'filter': filter })
```

Estou retornado o filtro no contexto pois acredito que você queira manter ele no campo de busca.